# jQuery post ValidateAntiForgeryToken fails

Tags: jquery, antiforgerytoken, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a simple jQuery that makes a post request to my API. If the API endpoint is decorated with the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute the post fails. I noticed that if I remove the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute the post is successful. I am not a jQuery lover and I have not idea how to solve it. This is part of my jQuery.

```
$.post("/api/endpoint", data, function (d) {
            if (d == "OK") {
                editDialog.modal('hide');
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should post `AntiForgeryToken` along with the `data` it should be in your form (hidden field)

Comment: Thanks, some idea how to do that?

Comment: get hidden field value and push it to data object or array, then check if that works